# fade in/out div when li is hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to `fade in` `div.imageHover` when hover the `li` and `fade out` when mouse out

here is my [**try**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWRLr/128/)

but the result is not what i expect.

**jquery**

```
(function($) {
        $(function() {
                $('.recentWorks >li').hover(function() {
               $('.imageHover').fadeToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    })(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the element within the current(hovered) `li`

```
$(this).find('.imageHover').fadeToggle("slow");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bLDhY/)

`$('.imageHover')` fetches all elements in the page with the class `imageHover`, but what you need is to limit the scope of the search to within the hovered `li` as given above. You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to do that.

Another option is to pass a [context to the jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) call like(it does the same thing as the above one)

```
$('.imageHover', this).fadeToggle("slow");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bLDhY/2/)

Comment: thank's it work and also thank's for your brief explanation in what area I mis.